# Addign sub views for single view while pressing the buttons

Tags: objective-c, addsubview

I am creating a project that on the top of view it will have buttons on scroll view like this < [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] >, defaultly i will display the first view as sub view. But by pressing second button i should get second view. Similarly i should get all the pages by clicking buttons. I am having one solution that, I want to create view for every individual part but it may cause memory issues. Please, provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be causing memory issues if create your views only when they're required and if you release your views appropriately before switching to another view.

Also, please kindly tag this question as an Objective C question.